# Java regex: find sequence of letter-digit combinations, allowing certain symbols

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to arrive at a regex to detect tokens from a sentence. These tokens should be a combination of letters and digits (mandatory), with optional chars like , or .

Given the sentence:

```
M5 x 35mm Full Thread Hexagon Bolts (DIN 933) - PEEK DescriptionThe M5 x 0.035mm, and 6NB7 plus a Go9IuN.
```

It should find six tokens:

```
M5, 35mm, M5, 0.035mm, 6NB7, Go9IuN
```

I have tried the following which does not work:

```
Pattern alphanum=Pattern.compile("\\b(([A-Za-z].*[0-9])|([0-9].*[A-Za-z]))\\b");
```

Any suggestions please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could  use a positive lookahead to assert at least 1 digit and then match at least 1 char a-zA-Z

The `.*` part will over match as it will match any char 0+ times except a newline

```
\b(?=[a-zA-Z0-9.,]*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9.,]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9.,]*\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` Word boundary
- `(?=[a-zA-Z0-9.,]*[0-9])` Assert at least 1 digit
- `[a-zA-Z0-9.,]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9.,]*` Match at least 1 char a-zA-Z
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uhfyQY/1)

In Java

```
final String regex = "\\b(?=[a-zA-Z0-9.,]*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9.,]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9.,]*\\b";
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. However perhaps I have not been clear in my post... I do not need to find 'M5 x 35mm' as one sequence (which is what your regex seems to capture?), but any individual tokens (separated by space) that is a letter and digit combination. The order of letter/digit does not matter... thanks

Comment: getting closer:) I modified it to '\b([A-Za-z][0-9]+)\b|\b([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?[A-za-z]*)\b' as it does not have to match just 'mm'. But this still does not capture other variations of letter/digit combination like '6NB7'. Please see my updated post... thanks

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the following regex will do the job

```
(?=[A-Za-z,.]*\d)(?=[\d,.]*[A-Za-z])[A-Za-z\d,.]{2,}(?<![,.])
```

It starts with two positive lookaheads which form an `and` condition.
The first lookahead `(?=[A-Za-z,.]*\d)` checks if a token contains at least one digit.
The second lookahead `(?=[\d,.]*[A-Za-z])` checks if it contains at least one letter.

The actual match `[A-Za-z\d,.]{2,}` reads at least two letters, digits, `,` or `.`.
In the end it checks that the match does not end with those special characters: `(?<![,.])`

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/EsbpUF/3)